# Factor unknown for cosine filter DFT

Tags: dft

To calculate the DFT of the fundamental frequency of a discrete signal,

Why multiply by $\frac 2N$ in the equation below? Where does that factor come from?
\begin{align}
C_{k_n} &= e^{-j\left(\frac{2\pi nk}{N}\right)}\\
C_{k_n}&=\left(\color{red}{\frac 2N}\right)\left[\cos\left(\frac{2\pi nk}{N}\right)+j\sin\left(\frac{2\pi nk}{N}\right)\right]=A_{k_n}+jB_{k_n}
\end{align}

Comment: Has been asked numerous times. The factor in front of a DFT is arbitrary. It's just a factor. It's often chosen to suit a specific need for the DFT – unitarity, for example, or, together with its inverse counterpart, being unitary. Plus, as for the last question, giving context and the source for your formula is always a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

There are several common scale factors used for differing definitions and implementations of the DFT, FFT, IFFT, and IDFT (1,1/N,1/sqrt(N),etc.).  Ones without 1/N in the DFT scale factor are commonly used to preserve a linear relationship to Parseval's theorem.  Ones with 1/N preserve pure integer-periodic-in-aperture sinusoidal magnitudes.